# Pronunciation of 三分 when it means three minutes

Tags: pronunciation

According to jisho, when 三分 means three minutes, it is pronounced さんぷん, however Google Translate mentions it as さんぶ. Are any of these wrong, or is it dialect? Are there other pronunciations?

Comment: [It can be a name](http://jisho.org/search/%E4%B8%89%E5%88%86%20%23names)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

「三分」 can be read in three different ways -- pun, bun, and bu.

"Three minutes": 「さん**ぷん**」

"One third": 「さん**ぶん**のいち」（三分の一）

"Percentage": 「**ぶ**」 "My batting average is 230." = 「ボクの[打率]{だりつ}は[二割三分]{にわりさんぶ}です。」

Comment: I believe さんふん is also acceptable for "three minites".

Comment: ぶ also was a currency unit during the Edo period.

Answer (score 2):

Jisho is correct, you should pronounce it さんぷん.

There are many way to read kanji and it is impossible to read all the kanji correct way for machine translation(including Google translate).